# Impossible to change my file on the serve

Tags: prestashop

I have a problem, I'm new to Prestashop, I created my child theme and I wanted to modify the description of a product in back, so I copied the file product.tpl to put it in my child theme (with the tree structure that goes with it).
I wanted to remove the truncate:

`<h2 class="h3 product-title" itemprop="name"><a href="{$product.url}" itemprop="url" content="{$product.url}">{$product.name|truncate:30:'...'}</a></h2>`

So I started by adding some crap to see if I was in the right place:

`<h2 class="h3 product-title" itemprop="name"><a href="{$product.url}" itemprop="url" content="{$product.url}">aze</a></h2>`

It worked, so I changed it to:

`<h2 class="h3 product-title" itemprop="name"><a href="{$product.url}" itemprop="url" content="{$product.url}">{$product.name}</a></h2>`

Except that "{$product.name}" didn't change and remained azeaze
So I tested:

`<h2 class="h3 product-title" itemprop="name"><a href="{$product.url}" itemprop="url" content="{$product.url}">Test</a></h2>`

And still only azeaze is left...

I tried to clear the cache, reboot the pc, delete the file and its tree (it comes back as it was before I touched it and if I create a new file no matter what word I'll have azeaze) as well as private browsing but nothing does it :/

If someone has an idea I'm interested because I really don't see why it doesn't work (the server is not down)

Thanks in advance if someone has an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your backoffice go to `Advenced Parameters -> Performance` and set `Template compilation` to `Recompile templates if the files have been updated`

[image: Picture of settings]